# Bash passing an array to a function inserts empty element

Tags: arrays, bash, function

I am passing an empty array to a function and within the function the array has one element but the element is empty.

```
#!/bin/bash
#ytest
#==============================================================
function ShowArray
{
echo "in ShowArray"

AlocalArray=("${!1}")

#alternatively you could do it like that
#echo "${AlocalArray[@]}"                      #DEBUG

echo "Showing content of array"

local iMax

   iMax=${#AlocalArray[*]}

   echo "ARRAYCOUNT: $iMax"
   for ((iItem=0; iItem < iMax ; iItem++))
   do
      echo "ITEM: ${AlocalArray[$iItem]}"
   done
}


declare -a AARRAY
echo "${AARRAY[@]}"                      #DEBUG
iMax=${#AARRAY[*]}

echo "HERE ARRAYCOUNT: $iMax ITEMS in ARRAY"
ShowArray "$AARRAY"
```

From the body of the script I get:

```
HERE ARRAYCOUNT: 0 ITEMS in ARRAY
```

From within the function I get:

```
in ShowArray
Showing content of array
ARRAYCOUNT: 1
ITEM:
```

What's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Disclaimer: this demo script does nothing useful and serves only the purpose to demonstrate the misbehaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct way to pass arrays in BASH and your `ShowArray` function is not accessing the same array created outside.

Here is how you can pass array in BASH (old and new versions)

```
# works for older BASH version 3 also
ShowArray() {
   echo "in ShowArray -----------------------"
   AlocalArray=("${!1}")
   declare -p AlocalArray
   echo "Showing content of array"

   local iMax=${#AlocalArray[@]}    
   echo "ARRAYCOUNT: $iMax"
   for ((iItem=0; iItem < iMax ; iItem++)); do
      echo "ITEM: ${AlocalArray[$iItem]}"
   done
}

# works on BASH versions >4
ShowArray1() {
   echo "in ShowArray1 -----------------------"
   declare -n AlocalArray="$1"
   declare -p AlocalArray
   echo "Showing content of array"

   local iMax=${#AlocalArray[@]}    
   echo "ARRAYCOUNT: $iMax"
   for ((iItem=0; iItem < iMax ; iItem++)); do
      echo "ITEM: ${AlocalArray[$iItem]}"
   done
}

declare -a AARRAY=(foo bar)
declare -p AARRAY
iMax=${#AARRAY[@]}
echo "HERE ARRAYCOUNT: $iMax ITEMS in ARRAY"
ShowArray "AARRAY[@]"
ShowArray1 "AARRAY"
```

**Output:**

```
declare -a AARRAY='([0]="foo" [1]="bar")'
HERE ARRAYCOUNT: 2 ITEMS in ARRAY
in ShowArray -----------------------
declare -a AlocalArray='([0]="foo" [1]="bar")'
Showing content of array
ARRAYCOUNT: 2
ITEM: foo
ITEM: bar
in ShowArray1 -----------------------
declare -n AlocalArray="AARRAY"
Showing content of array
ARRAYCOUNT: 2
ITEM: foo
ITEM: bar
```

Comment: I have another question on the same tolpic. Maybe you can help me there as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015565/bash-adding-a-string-with-a-space-to-an-array-adds-two-elements