# bash adding a string with a space to an array adds two elements

Tags: arrays, string, bash, space

Hi I am having an array and want to add strings that contain spaces. How can this be done?
the following example code shows what I want to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

# works on BASH versions >4
ShowArray1() {
   echo "in ShowArray1 -----------------------"
   declare -n AlocalArray="$1"
   declare -p AlocalArray
   echo "Showing content of array"

   local iMax=${#AlocalArray[@]}    
   echo "ARRAYCOUNT: $iMax"
   for ((iItem=0; iItem < iMax ; iItem++)); do
      echo "ITEM: ${AlocalArray[$iItem]}"
   done
}

declare -a AARRAY
#declare -p AARRAY
iMax=${#AARRAY[@]}
echo "HERE ARRAYCOUNT: $iMax ITEMS in ARRAY"

ShowArray1 "AARRAY"
sParam="1st Item"
AARRAY+=($sParam)

ShowArray1 "AARRAY"
```

Problem is that the Item "1st Item" is added as two elements into the array. Output:

```
Showing content of array
ARRAYCOUNT: 2
ITEM: 1st
ITEM: Item
```

Answer (score 9):

Double quote the variable to prevent the expansion:

```
AARRAY+=("$sParam")
```